# Cannot open Office documents - repeating log in window

Tags: office-365, security

we use SharePoint 2019 on-premise and Office 365. Sometimes some users have problem when they open Word or Excel, it opens Windows Security window and after log in,it is repeatly opening. I know, that this is happend for Outlook and also it solved the same way, user need remove MicrosoftOffice16_Data:SSPI credential from Windows Credentials. But we have problem only with document stored on SharePoint and after we started use O365. Where is problem?